# How to set value el-input in function in js

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

How to set the value of el-input after enter click in el-input of plaid

```html
<el-form-item :label="$t('elements.latitude')" prop="latitude">
     <el-input
          v-model="createForm.latitude"
          :value="latValue"
        />
</el-form-item>
<el-form-item :label="$t('elements.plaid')" prop="plaid">
        <el-input
          v-model="createForm.plaid"
          @keyup.enter.native="queryPlaid"
        />
      </el-form-item>
```

Fuction of @keyup.enter.native

```js
queryPlaid(){
  axios.get('/api/get_lat',
       {
         params: {
           plaid: this.createForm.plaid,
         },
       })
     .then(response => {
       const data = response.data;
       this.createForm.latitude = data.latitude;
     });
}
```

Some one knew how to set the value of el-input?

Answer (score 0):

`value` binding shouldn't be necessary. Let 2 way v-model binding handle it for you and mutate that

```
<el-form-item :label="$t('elements.latitude')" prop="latitude">
     <el-input v-model="createForm.latitude" />
</el-form-item>
```

```
queryPlaid(){
  this.createForm.latitude = this.createForm.plaid;
}
```

Comment: already tried this one, but I cant type anymore in  <el-input v-model="createForm.latitude" />,if I don't like to type in plaid el-input. I'm planning of querying plaid input to database then put the result to latitude input.

Comment: Make sure the field `this.createForm.latitude` exists on initialization (defined in data) of the component, there is something with element-ui which won't let you "change" the field anymore.

Comment: Exactly what @dreijntjens said. Your snippet doens't contain the data/computed properties. For v-model binding to work, your property has to be initiailized in your data properties

Comment: yes, something is wrong with element-ui. I didn't go any further to query plaid, I only choose typing of latitude manually, already scratch querying plaid. Thanks.